# Is there a way to compute the ViewState MAC?

Tags: asp.net, proxy, viewstate

We are writing a proxy cache for a .NET application, and we are having problems with the ViewState MAC on the proxy. We have disabled the MAC Validation in order to get pass over this issue, but is not the best way to go (for security reasons).

Is there a way to compute the ViewState MAC on the proxy in order to pass the validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this article on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx
My guess is that you need to make sure the machine key is the same on the proxy server as on your web application server.

Comment: Making sure we have the same machineKey on both servers is the right way to solve the problem.